# reverse video doesn't seem to be working

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, xterm, ansi-escape

I'm trying to enable reverse video on bash / xterm such that the text is black but the foreground is white. But it's not working. Here's my command:

```
echo -n -e \\x1B\\x07maaa\\x1B[m
```

Any ideas why it's not behaving as expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example

```
echo -n -e \\x1B\\x07maaa\\x1B[m
```

the `\\x07m` cannot be correct, since that would be an ASCII BEL.  Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
echo -n -e \\x1B[7maaa\\x1B[m
```

The `\\x1B` is the *escape* character.  All of the other characters are from the printable-ASCII range.  This assumes that your `echo` interprets escapes in that manner (bash's does).

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
echo -n -e "\e[07mTEXT\e[0m"
```

Or:

```
printf "\e[07mTEXT\e[0m"
```

Answer (score 1):

More portable are

```
tput rev
```

for reverse mode and

```
tput sgr0
```

to clear reverse mode.

Comment: true, but the question *was* about escape sequences

Comment: I'm trying to make some updates to a vt100 terminal emulator so understanding how the ANSI escape codes work (vs. how tput works) is very beneficial. None-the-less, I was unaware of `tput`.

Answer (score 1):

It will be far simpler to use `bash`'s `printf` command (and as Thomas Dickey pointed out, you're using the wrong sequence to enable inverse video). Asking yourself how many backslashes you need to stack up is almost always the wrong question.

```
# \e[7m starts inverse video
# \e[m (short for \e[0m) resets all video parameters to their default values
printf '\e[7maaa\e[m'
```